# SQL Server Procedure with Encryption input Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption, source-code-protection

I am new at using procedure with encryption, I tried altering my procedures to encrytped procedure. When there is no input parameter something like,

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Stock] WITH ENCRYPTION
     -- @Input_Parameter1 nvarchar(50) -> gives syntax error
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    select * from Inventory
END
```

It works. But when I add some input parameters between `WITH ENCRYPTION` and `as` it throws an error. How can I do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

just you miss syntaxes

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Stock] 
@Input_Parameter1 nvarchar(50) --> gives syntax error
WITH ENCRYPTION
...
```

Comment: @AliCAKIL glad it helps you

Answer (score 2):

The `WITH ENCRYPTION` clause needs to be specified after the parameter declarations:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Stock] 

@Input_Parameter1 nvarchar(50) 

WITH ENCRYPTION

AS

BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

SELECT * FROM dbo.Inventory;

END;
```